# Javascript CSS Value Changes on .val()

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the beginning of my JS, I set several `input` fields to readonly as well as set their *background-color* to lightgrey using JQuery `.attr()` and `.css()` functions.

Everything runs fine and dandy, until I use `.val()` to change the value of the input fields. This doesn't reset their readonly attribute, but it does reset their background-color(s) to white.

EX:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  $("#target").attr("readonly", "true");
  $("#target").css("background-color", "lightgrey");

});

//function called by various events: .click(), .blur()
function myfunction(){
  $("#target").val(42).trigger("change");
}
```

Now I realize that I could reset the css using the `.css()` function, but doing that on the fly is very slow and noticeable(long enough for the user to see the change). I also ***cannot*** edit the html document to include these default styles nor the css sheet due to the nature of the project.

Comment: You are not resetting the style in the code you've posted, `.val()` will never affect the style on it's own. It's possible the page is replacing the input or resetting it somehow, if you cannot edit the page then you will need to reset the background colour yourself. (Potentially you could listen for the change and do it automatically? It depends on why the page is changing the colour, which we cannot see from the info in this question)

Comment: what is your change event

Comment: @DBS I feared as much, the document I'm writing has other scripts running on it that I'm not "allowed" to look at(I can with view source). So it is very likely my change is triggering another event which resets the actual html. If that's the case then I may be dead in the water.

Comment: Are you working on an injected script? (e.g. using greasemonkey or tampermonkey) If so, potentially sharing the site you're modifying may let us help more.

Comment: @DBS Unfortunately I am extremely limited in what I can share, it is injected script. However it is on a local server, it's all confidential, and I can only share functional information, nothing specific. I'm sorry I can't be more specific. I guess for now the users will have to deal with the slowness in resetting the css after the value is set.